# Reverse digits of a list of numbers in python

Tags: python, list, integer, reverse

```
for i in range(len(primo)):
    reversed_num = 0
    while i > 0:
       digit = i % 10
       reversed_num = reversed_num * 10 + digit
       i //= 10
       reversed.append (reversed_num)
    
for r in range(len(reversed)):
    print (r)
```

I'm writing a program to reverse a series of numbers from a list. For example:

Input: 1234,124,654

Output: 4321,421,456

The script works correctly with one number, but with a list it doesn't work properly.

EDIT:
......................................

This is the working whole code.

```
#program to find the multiple of the first number that summed to its reverse creates a number divisible for the second number chosen. Results are shown up to five digits.

import sys

def main():
    x = 0
    y = 0
    k = 0
    z = 0
    print ("Hello! Let's compare some numbers!\nPress input to continue")
    input()
    print ("Insert the first number")
    x = input()
    print ("Insert the second number")
    y = input()
    print()
    
    primo = []
    secondo = []
    
    #list multiples
    
    while k < 99999:
        k = int(k) + int(x)
        print (k)
        primo.append (k)
        
    while z < 99999:
        z = int(z) + int(y)
        print(z)
        secondo.append (z)
        
    print("The numbers have been calculated! Press to proceed")

    input()
    
    print("LOADING...")

    #reverse all numbers of the first list
    
    def myReverser(n: float) -> float:
       return float(''.join(list(reversed(str(n)))))
    
    reversedList = [myReverser(i) for i in primo]
    reversedList = [int(i) for i in reversedList]
    
    #sum the multiple of the first number and its reversed and search common values in res and secondo
    
    res = [
    x
    for x, y in zip(primo, reversedList)
    if (x + y) in secondo
]

    print()
    print()

    if len(res) == 0:
        print ("No results found")
    else:
        print ("The numbers are: ", res)

    #ending

    print ()
    print ("Thank you for using my program!")
    print ()
    choice = input ("Would you try with another number? [Y/N] ").capitalize()

    if choice == "Y":
        main()
    if choice == "N":
        sys.exit()

main()

#no copyright intended. This code is open-source. Feel free to use it in other projects.
```

The script can compare the two given numbers to find the multiple of the first number that summed to its reverse creates a number divisible for the second number chosen. Results are shown up to five digits.

Comment: is '1234,124,654' a list of lists or list? [[1234],[124],[654]] or [1234,124,654]?

Comment: primo is your input? reversed in the output ?

Comment: The list is:  primo = [1234,124,654]

Comment: I do not understand this line of code : `reversed.append (reversed_num)` I know that reversed is a Built-in Function in python How can this happen ( reversed . ) ? @Andrea Valsesia

Comment: ????????? @Andrea Valsesia

Comment: @FadyHany in that case "reversed" has been redefined as the name of a list. Now, I changed the code using the built-in function. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Andrea Valsesia So in this line of the old code ( the code before the last edit ) :       

`reversed.append (reversed_num)`

`reversed` was a list not the Built-in Function , right ?

Comment: @FadyHany exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice try, but what about a function that reverses the numbers? You should be happy to know that `reversed` already exists in Python, and you can use it this way:

```
>>> list(reversed(str(0.1223142131)))
['1', '3', '1', '2', '4', '1', '3', '2', '2', '1', '.', '0']
>>> float(''.join(reversed(str(0.1223142131))))
1312413221.0
```

so you can implement your own function:

```
def myReverser(n: float) -> float:
    return float(''.join(reversed(str(n))))
```

and then use it over the whole `list`:

```
reversedList = [myReverser(i) for i in [1234, 124, 654]]
```

---

If you don't want the `.0` at the end of all the numbers, this means that you don't want floating point numbers, but `int`egers, so you can just do this:

```
reversedList = [int(i) for i in reversedList]
```

Comment: I tried to run this script and it works. But, there's still a little problem... there is a point zero after each number. Example: 4321.0, 321.0, 654.0  Is there a way to fix that? In every case, this will not compromise the result of following operations. Right?

Comment: Oh, the .0 is caused by the float() conversion, if you don't want it you just have to use int instead of float, let me edit the answer. (Ovviamente non compromette nessunissima operazione)

Comment: @AndreaValsesia, I edited my answer, if it worked accept it, otherwise feel free to ask me in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are only printing the range of the length, so I don't know how this would print your numbers at all. Here is a brief method that does what you are after, I believe.

```
In [1]: [int(str(x)[::-1]) for x in [1234, 124, 654]]
Out[1]: [4321, 421, 456]
```

or:

```py
def reverse_items(l: list[int]) -> list[int]:
    return [int(str(x)[::-1]) for x in l]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(reverse_items([4321, 421, 456]))
```

output:

```
[1234, 124, 654]
```

This creates a list of integer values generated from reversing the string values of given list items.

Comment: It's quite a bad idea to overwrite the built-in function reversed.

Comment: Yeah, it is. Especially in a help forum context. I'll fix that right now.

Comment: I don't know if there's any difference between reverse() and [::-1], but this works, so +1

Answer (score 1):

You can reverse a list in Python using the built-in `reverse()` or `reversed()` methods. These methods will reverse the list without creating a new list. Python `reverse()` and `reversed()` will reverse the elements in the original list object.

Comment: Doesn't reverse(), reverse the element order but not the order of the digits with in each element? like [1234, 124, 654] would be [654, 124, 1234] rather than [4321,421,456].

Comment: Yeah, but that would work very well with a list comprehension : `[reverse(e) for e in myList]`.

Answer (score 1):

A *string-free* approach based on the old polynomial representation of numbers. Compute the quotients and remainders by a recursive long division and keeping track of them as pair in a list. Once the breaking condition is hit travel the list with a decreasing powers of 10.

```
def digit_reverser(n):
    
    def base_10_representation(n):
        d = []
        q, r = divmod(n, 10) # quotient, remainder
        d.append((q, r)) 
        if q < 10:
            return d
        d.extend(base_10_representation(q))
        return d

    # reversing the digits    
    d = base_10_representation(n)
    n_digits = len(d)
    return sum(r*10**(n_digits-i) for i, (_, r) in enumerate(d)) + d[-1][0]

n = 123456789
d = digit_reverser(n)

print(d)
```

**Output**

```
987654321
```

For an extension to list of numbers:

```
nrs = [1234, 124, 654]
nrs_rev = [digit_reverser(n) for n in nrs]
```

**Output**

```
[4321, 421, 456]
```

Answer (score 0):

code:

```
l = input().split(',')
l = list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda d: int(d), x))[::-1], l))
print(l)
```

input:

```
123,456,789
```

output:

```
[[3, 2, 1], [6, 5, 4], [9, 8, 7]]
```